# Cannot launch Pharo on Windows 10 - SDL2.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error

Tags: pharo

I feel a bit silly to ask this, but... When I try to run the Pharo Laucher in my 64-bits Windows 10, I get:

[image]

I have tried to copy the last 64-bits stable nd overwrite the files but it is the same. Trying to run directly Pharo.exe, even using the command line, always gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Can it run from a simple directory (one word) close to c: ? Earlier versions run fine on my machines. Other possible issues: do you have full rights on that machine, or is your antivirus protection too aggressive?

Comment: Thanks but not. I tried to copy the whole directory to c:\PharoLauncher and still got the same message. I am administrator on this machine, also tried to run it as administrator. The antivirus says nothing about this.

Comment: Better luck with the latest bleeding edge? http://files.pharo.org/pharo-launcher/bleedingEdge/

Comment: No :-( It says that the version I had installed is more recent

Comment: Hmm. On my Windows 10 machine I installed it 2020-12-9. That works fine. There are two other possible issues I've seen: a graphical driver problem and a Linux subsystem confusing the platform detection

Comment: I have another Windows 10 machine and it also works fine there. But another colleague and me have this problem on our office computers. It must be some corporate configuration, but I don't know how to detect the cause/incompatibility.

Comment: System administration has lots of things they can configure that would stop Pharo from running. The fastest solution will probably come from asking your local administrator to take a look